# How can I fix this SubSurf Modifier issue?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying in vain to reproduce the following image. I tried all I know to maintain the straightness of the edges by applying a crease of 1 and by adding edges but as I apply a SubSurf it's a 'disaster' . Idealy I would like to have the edges not too sharp as we can see on the image.
Thanks for you help.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried beveling? You can use the modifier, or you can use `Ctrl`+`B` in edit mode, with the desired edges selected.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a part of a sphere. I need to apply a Subsurf to smooth the surface of the sphere that's why I use (try to use) the crease to keep the edges sharp.

Comment: Bevel still should work

Comment: I don't know how to solve the issue of the angles. Why the crease doesn't work nor the insert of edges?

Comment: That kind of geometry looks a lot more suited for actual hard-edge style modeling, not Subdivision modeling. Geometric shapes and hard surfaced mechanical stuff don't usually play well with subdivided

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the sort of thing that is best modeled using hard edge surface modelling, with manual placement of edges instead of using a subdivision surface modifier that will round everything off, then keep constantly fighting against it to try and keep sharp corners and tight edges.

Anyway, edge creases seem to work, all you need is an extra inset, then set edge crease to 1 on **all** corner diagonal edges.

[image: Sphere inset]

Or alternatively you could instead use full control-edge-loops all around the sphere to keep smoothing from propagating too far.

Select the four edgeloops limiting the indented area and bevel them with the bevel tool <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

[image: Edgeloops 00]

Select the relevant parts and extrude them inwards by vertex normal

[image: Edgeloops 01]

Now add control edge loops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> around every sharp edge so smoothing won't propagate too far

[image: Edgeloops 02]

Repeat for all necessary corners inside and outside where the edges must be sharp

Comment: thanks but could you detail the way you do the grooves on a sphere?

Comment: Certainly, edited the answers above, see if its clear enough now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to copy the object in the picture, which is flat, or are your trying to create a square hole into a spherical/round object?

For a square into a sphere, the following method has the advantage of adding no edge loop around the sphere (which can mess up the topology) and no pinching on the corners:

[image]