# Inset on a cylinder causing pinching when using subsurf modifier and sharp edges

Tags: modeling, edges

In my attached picture I have a cyclinder where I'm trying to inset along 3 faces. I've tried every combination of creases, sharp edges, with and without an edge modifier. I can't seem to get the desired result. I just want a sharp edge.

I'd rather not use lots of edge loops as there's a LOT more geometery above the cylinder that I dont want to start splitting.

Does anyone know the proper way to approach this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/how-can-i-fix-this-subsurf-modifier-issue/66170#66170

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've looked at the question you've posted prior to me asking this but still can't seem to get this to work. It appears that in the question posted that having only the loop extrude inwards affects the final geometery. I'm extruding the whole face inwards which still causes this problem. I've  just revisited the question and tried a few other things but it's still not working

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81596/how-can-i-make-a-rounded-indentation-on-a-cylinder/81605#81605 I don't think you need any additional loopcuts, all you need to do is extrude said faces inwards then crease them along with the corners

Comment: I've proposed an alternative, maybe it will answer?